# How to provide configuration data for Dagger 2?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am looking into the Dagger 2 framework to see if it is useful for our stand alone applications which include configuration data provided on the command line.

I have previously found it very beneficial to use `@Inject @Named("xxx") String s` to have the injection framework inject configuration strings, which for Dagger 1 could be done with a provider in the @Module looking similar to:

```
@Provides @Named(XXX) String provideClassType(ConfigurationMap configurationMap) {
    return configurationMap.get(XXX);
}
```

where `configurationMap` was passed in to the constructor when I manually instantiated the Module.  Apparently this mechanism has changed so Dagger instantiates the module by itself, so I cannot pass in my configuration map as I've done so far.  I've thought of sneaking it in by setting a static field before invoking the builder() method, but it doesn't feel right (and is probably not threadsafe either).

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out after rereading the documentation, that modules with a non-default constructor must be provided explicitly to the builder:

```
DaggerXXX_XXX.builder().myModule(new MyModule(new ConfigurationMap()).build()
```

(where the MyModule constructor saves the configurationMap field)